# saving streaming video played in web browser is off-topic on superuser?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen-request

I really want to save this video as I love the show but I have some troubles with their fast English ...  so ... I asked here [any-idea-how-to-save-video-from-this-site](https://superuser.com/questions/163517/any-idea-how-to-save-video-from-this-site-closed) and the question was closed as off topic.

I read the faq, I went through metasuperuser but still cannot get why the question was closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why it got closed as off-topic, but otherwise I would have closed it as not being a real question.

Not that there isn't a question, but I feel that you didn't put in sufficient effort for someone else to put in any to answer it.

You did not take the effort to copy paste the question header into the body, so that it actually looks like a question.

> http://ten.com.au/lie-to-me.htm
>
> as my favourite firefox plugin doesn't
>   work :-(

What is your favorite firefox pluging? I always like to think I'm a psychic, but I'm probably not.

Furthermore, it might be violating copyright, in which case we shouldn't be giving you the tools to do so.

```
2010 Copyright Network Ten
```

So there you have it. This site is simply not appropriate for your question, sorry.

Comment: Yes, in general, a site which is making country detection while streaming videos is usually a site which doesn't want you to bypass their reader, unfortunately for you.

Comment: 1) the question is in the title of the question. I thought it was good enough. 2) I didn't name the plugin :-( I have to be more specific next time. 3) and more importantly I did not think about the copyright thing at all.  Thank you for explanation

Comment: The lack of clarity and the copyright issue is precisely why I voted to close (though I believe I voted too-localized)